# Unable to create hbase table from hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

This is my query below which i am running, but i am getting an exception. I kept all jars in hive/lib folder but still i am facing this issue. Can anyone give me suggestion how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE hbase_shipper(s_id int,s_name string)STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,cf1:val")TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name"="hive_shipper");


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:MetaException(message:java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:156)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2098)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:631)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 48 more
)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.getHBaseAdmin(HBaseStorageHandler.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:156)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.createTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
)
```

Jars in hive/lib:

```
accumulo-core-1.6.0.jar               commons-vfs2-2.0.jar                    hbase-thrift-1.0.3.jar                jsr305-3.0.0.jar
accumulo-fate-1.6.0.jar               curator-client-2.6.0.jar                hive-accumulo-handler-1.2.1.jar       jta-1.1.jar
accumulo-start-1.6.0.jar              curator-framework-2.6.0.jar             hive-ant-1.2.1.jar                    junit-4.11.jar
accumulo-trace-1.6.0.jar              curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar               hive-beeline-1.2.1.jar                libfb303-0.9.2.jar
activation-1.1.jar                    datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar           hive-cli-1.2.1.jar                    libthrift-0.9.2.jar
ant-1.9.1.jar                         datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar             hive-common-1.2.1.jar                 log4j-1.2.16.jar
ant-launcher-1.9.1.jar                datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar             hive-contrib-1.2.1.jar                mail-1.4.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar                       derby-10.10.2.0.jar                     hive-exec-1.2.1.jar                   maven-scm-api-1.4.jar
antlr-runtime-3.4.jar                 eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar          hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar          maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar
apache-curator-2.6.0.pom              geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar  hive-hwi-1.2.1.jar                    maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar
apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar        geronimo-jaspic_1.0_spec-1.0.jar        hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar                   mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar
asm-commons-3.1.jar                   geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar         hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar        netty-3.7.0.Final.jar
asm-tree-3.1.jar                      groovy-all-2.1.6.jar                    hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar              opencsv-2.3.jar
avro-1.7.5.jar                        guava-14.0.1.jar                        hive-serde-1.2.1.jar                  oro-2.0.8.jar
bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar              hamcrest-core-1.1.jar                   hive-service-1.2.1.jar                paranamer-2.3.jar
calcite-avatica-1.2.0-incubating.jar  hbase-annotations-1.0.3.jar             hive-shims-0.20S-1.2.1.jar            parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar
calcite-core-1.2.0-incubating.jar     hbase-annotations-1.0.3-tests.jar       hive-shims-0.23-1.2.1.jar             pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.jar
calcite-linq4j-1.2.0-incubating.jar   hbase-checkstyle-1.0.3.jar              hive-shims-1.2.1.jar                  php
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar           hbase-client-1.0.3.jar                  hive-shims-common-1.2.1.jar           plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar      hbase-common-1.0.3.jar                  hive-shims-scheduler-1.2.1.jar        py
commons-cli-1.2.jar                   hbase-common-1.0.3-tests.jar            hive-testutils-1.2.1.jar              regexp-1.3.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar                 hbase-examples-1.0.3.jar                htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar      servlet-api-2.5.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar         hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.3.jar          httpclient-4.4.jar                    snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
commons-compiler-2.7.6.jar            hbase-hadoop-compat-1.0.3.jar           httpcore-4.4.jar                      ST4-4.0.4.jar
commons-compress-1.4.1.jar            hbase-it-1.0.3.jar                      ivy-2.4.0.jar                         stax-api-1.0.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar         hbase-it-1.0.3-tests.jar                janino-2.7.6.jar                      stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar                  hbase-prefix-tree-1.0.3.jar             jcommander-1.32.jar                   super-csv-2.2.0.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar              hbase-protocol-1.0.3.jar                jdo-api-3.0.1.jar                     tempus-fugit-1.1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar          hbase-resource-bundle-1.0.3.jar         jetty-all-7.6.0.v20120127.jar         velocity-1.5.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar                    hbase-rest-1.0.3.jar                    jetty-all-server-7.6.0.v20120127.jar  xz-1.0.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar                  hbase-server-1.0.3.jar                  jline-2.12.jar                        zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar             hbase-server-1.0.3-tests.jar            joda-time-2.5.jar
commons-math-2.1.jar                  hbase-shell-1.0.3.jar                   jpam-1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar                hbase-testing-util-1.0.3.jar            json-20090211.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace,

`Caused by : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup`

The `netty-3.7.0.Final.jar`does not come with this class. Replace this with a latest (>=4.0) version of `netty-all-4.0.x.Final.jar`.

Comment: thank u but now i am getting this exception: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V

Comment: Looks like compatibility issue. Can you please update the post with versions of hadoop, hive and Hbase?

Comment: Hadoop 2.6.0
Hive : 1.2.1 Hbase : 1.0.3

Comment: This is a known compatibility issue. Hive 1.x is compatible with Hbase 0.98.x and lower versions.Refer [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10990) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) to know how to workaround this.

Comment: so to change hbase version is it required to give required hbase jars or i have to change whole hbase version for writing this query?

Comment: You might have to change the target Hbase version for hive1.2.1 to support or upgrade Hive.